# Can I give a Linux user rights to do exactly the same as another user?

Tags: linux, file-permissions

Related to my question: "[How can I configure Cassandra to create files with custom rights?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19792827)". I'm trying to approach the problem from the OS level.

Given two different Linux users - `cassandra` and `tomcat7` - can I give `tomcat7` read access rights to all the files which have read access rights by `cassandra`? The files are only `o+rw` (so I can't play around with groups); Cassandra keeps creating new files all the time so setting the group permissions manually isn't an option.

Comment: Maybe you can solve your problem with Access Control Lists (man acl, setfacl, getfacl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try changing the default file permission of the cassandra user using `umask`, assuming the mask isn't hard coded into Cassandra. This would allow you to add tomcat7 to the default cassandra user group with read/write access.

Somewhere in the shell profile or other config file for cassandra there is likely to be a line referencing umask with a setting of 077 or 0077.  Replacing the first 7 with a 0 will allow rw for the group on all new files created.  It is likely to be in the shell profile as it has it's own user, but it is sometime part of an application configuration file.  You will of course need to change the file permissions of existing files, but this should be trivial.

The man pages don't do a brilliant job at explaining the ins and outs of the umask, but there is a nice tutorial on [Understanding umask settings](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html) on Nix Craft.  However, to guard against link rot, googling "linux umask" chucks up a whole bunch of tutorials from everyman and his dog.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this

1) alter the uid in the password file to be the same for cassandra and tomcat7.  Add cassandra and tomcat7 to the same set of groups

To show this actually works

a) add a user, I used the command

```
sudo adduser likeme --shell /usr/bin/zsh
```

I added a different shell so it is immediately apparent that this entry is being used

b) alter the uid in the /etc/passwd file.  I used this command and edited the file so that the uid for my normal login (jamie) is used as the uid for the new user.

```
sudo vipw
```

c) test the new user.  Here is what happens

```
$ who am i
jamie    pts/10       2013-11-06 19:04 (:0.0)
$ sudo su - likeme
%
```

Note the prompt has changed because a different shell is being used.  However:

```
% id
uid=1000(jamie) gid=1000(jamie) groups=1000(jamie)
```

It still says I am me!!
This is because in a fundamental way the two users *are the same*.  You might say that there are two usernames but only one user.

2) configure sudo to allow tomcat7 to become cassandra

```
tomcat7  ALL = (cassandra:cassandra) ALL
```

Comment: I strongly object to altering the UID in the `/etc/passwd`.  If the altered user already has files with the original UID, these will no longer belong to him then.  But I like the `sudo` solution a lot.

Comment: @Alfe you might strongly object but it answers the OP's question and it works.

Comment: `tomcat7` is already in the sudoers file as `tomcat7 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL)` and as `tomcat7 ALL=(cassandra:cassandra) ALL` but still can't read `cassandra`'s files.

Comment: I'm going to try #1, setting the UID of `tomcat7` to be that of `cassandra` and then I'll update the owner UID of all existing `tomcat7` files. I'll come back with feedback a bit later.

Comment: Changing the UID doesn't work. Two users can't have the same UID. I'm still working on the `sudoers` thing, because for some reason it doesn't seem to work (sudo works from the console, but Priam acts as if it can't sudo). I'll be back with feedback again later.

Comment: What sort of Linux/Unix/BSD are you using?  I've tried this before on several different flavours of OS and it has always worked.  I mean making the uid the same

Comment: Added stuff to answer to demo uid copying working, please try

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are also interested about non-system users which are supposed to be allowed to act as the other user, I would just allow him to log on as the other user.

If you are reluctant to just give him the password of the other user, then you can allow him to log on via ssh (locally) and pre-shared keys.  For this, generate a key (`ssh-keygen`), store it in `~cassandra/.ssh/` and put the public part also in `~tomcat7/.ssh/authorized_keys`.  User `cassandra` should then be able to just switch to the other user using `ssh tomcat7@localhost`.

Comment: This is not about regular users and passwords. These are Linux services which run as their own user. Cassandra is a database server and Tomcat is a web server. I have very little control over what they do and I can't simply ask Tomcat to `sudo` or `ssh`. The web application running on Tomcat is Priam and I'd have to change its code and recompile it if I were to make it get the rights of Cassandra. That's not a problem right now, but it means there's a lot more maintenance to do in the future if we upgrade to a newer version of Priam.

Comment: So you think in your situation my proposal isn't applicable.  Does that make the answer bad in general?  For my situations my solution often works perfectly.

Comment: And users should wait a bit more than a few seconds before demanding explanations.

Comment: Why wait until the downvoter is gone and never comes back to see the question for the reason? ;-)  I think downvoters first should explain in comments and then downvote, but that's up to you, I can always remove comments asking for reasons.

Comment: That's right, it isn't applicable in any way. What you answered is about how someone can authenticate as another, not how two users can get the same right. This is about Linux users, not people who interact with the system using a terminal.

Comment: I want to point out that your question is based on your situation but not limited to it.  You never said that you are only interested in answers concerning system users who cannot use ssh to become each other.  Your example was in this field, but you never limited it to this.  So I can accept if you think my answer does not suit you, but I don't see a good reason for downvoting it.

Comment: You phrased 'users' and meant Unix user entities.  I understood people.  But I won't damn you for not being more specific.

Comment: I added a small prefix to my answer stating my assumptions.